# Python import csv and randomly select rows and print with other random values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry but im new to Python.

Ive created a Colab notebook using Python to import a CSV. I want it to randomly select 3 rows from the CSV. The problem is that it keeps selecting the same row. How do i get it to randomly select 3 rows and print it together with another random value?

My code so far:

```
import csv
import random

names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2','Name 3','Name 4','Name 5', 'Name 6', 'Name 
7','Name 8', 'Name 9', 'Name 10']

with open('Sheet.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

next(csv_reader) #skips header in csv

chosen_row = random.choice(list(csv_reader))

paraone = (chosen_row[1])

for num in range (3):
  area = random.choice(names)

  print(f'{area}\n{paraone}\n')
```

**That outputs:**

Name 10
this is paragraph 10

Name 5
this is paragraph 10

Name 1
this is paragraph 10

**But what i want is something like:**

Name 10
this is paragraph 2

Name 5
this is paragraph 8

Name 1
this is paragraph 10

**My csv is like this:**

[image]

Comment: paste what you have tried here instead of links to somewhere else.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried here as text on SO so others can help identify your problem

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Ok ive edited my question above. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a Seed to the random function.

```
random.seed()
```

You can read more here: https://pynative.com/python-random-seed/